# Is there a word for a number that can be expressed as an exponential with the same base and exponent?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, terminology

Some examples:
\begin{align*}
1 &= 1^1 \\
4 &= 2^2 \\
27 &= 3^3 \\
256 &= 4^4 \\
3125 &= 5^5 \\
\end{align*}
and so on.  Is there a name for these types of numbers?  It seems like there should be.

Comment: As exponentiation is repeated multiplication, *tetration* is a term for repeated exponentiation.  The simplest case would be a number raised to itself as a power.

Comment: [Self power](http://www.math.toronto.edu/canghel/SelfPowerMapCAnghel.pdf) ?